# A Simple Cluster Generator v0.1

Tags: c++, beginner, c++11, random, clustering

[NOTE] This question can be depreciated in favor of [version 0.2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/172754/a-simple-cluster-generator-v0-2).

The purpose of this code is to produce a universe of points, randomly generated around predetermined centroids, provided as a vector of vector. The final product is a file of sample points, to be used for fake data analysis in another program. The objective here was brevity and speed - I feel the code could be vastly concisified, but it is working.

Detailed description of the primary algorithm parameters is in the .h.

```
// clustergen.h

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

#ifndef CLUSTERGEN_H
#define CLUSTERGEN_H

// POINT GENERATION - COMMON USER DEFINED VARIABLES
double const PT_BOUND = 10;   // Defines the +/- around a centroid for point generation if UNIFORM
double const PT_SD = 5;       // Defines the stddev around a centroid for point generation if NORMAL

// PRIMARY ALGORITHM
void clustergen(unsigned int k, std::vector<std::vector<double>> &c, std::string file_out, std::string file_rpt, bool csv, bool norm);
// Produces [k] points in [file_out]; all points are separated by line breaks
// If [csv] = 0, dimensions for each point are whitespace-separated
// If [csv] = 1, dimensions for each point are comma-separated
// If [norm] = 0, points will be UNIFORMLY generated around centroids
// If [norm] = 1, points will be NORMALLY generated around centroids
// [c] is a vector of vectors; it's size is the number of centroids
// The first insertion in [c] sets dimensional precedence; dimensional mismatches are always omitted/avoided.

#endif //CLUSTERGEN_H





// clustergen.cpp

#include "clustergen.h"

void clustergen(unsigned int k, std::vector<std::vector<double>> &c, std::string file_out, std::string file_rpt, bool csv, bool norm) {

    std::ofstream fout, rout;
    fout.open(file_out);
    rout.open(file_rpt);

    rout << "CLUSTERGEN STATUS REPORT FOLLOWS...\n";

    unsigned int ct = 0;
    unsigned int cl_ct = 0;

    for (std::vector<std::vector<double>>::iterator c_iter = c.begin(); c_iter != c.end(); ++c_iter) {
        unsigned int subsec;
        std::default_random_engine gen(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());

        (k % c.size() == 0) ? (subsec = (k + ct) / c.size()) : (subsec = 1 + ((k + ct) / c.size()));
        k -= subsec;

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < subsec; i++) {
            std::vector<double>::iterator d_iter = (*c_iter).begin();
            while (d_iter != (*c_iter).end()) {
                double num;
                if (norm) {
                    std::normal_distribution<double> distr((*d_iter), PT_SD);
                    num = distr(gen);
                } else {
                    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distr((*d_iter) - PT_BOUND, (*d_iter) + PT_BOUND);
                    num = distr(gen);
                }
                fout << num;
                std::vector<double>::iterator temp_d_iter = d_iter;
                std::vector<std::vector<double>>::iterator temp_c_iter = c_iter;
                if (++temp_d_iter != (*c_iter).end()) {
                    (csv == 0) ? (fout << " ") : (fout << ",");
                } else if ((i != subsec - 1) || (++temp_c_iter != c.end())) {
                    fout << "\n";
                }
                ++d_iter;
            }
            ++ct;
        }
        rout << "\n" << div << " points ";
        (norm) ? (rout << "normally") : (rout << "uniformly");
        rout << " distributed around centroid " << ++cl_ct << " ...";
    }
    rout << "\n\n" << ct << " total points assigned.";
}





// main.cpp
#include "clustergen.h"

int main() {

    std::vector<std::vector<double>> v = {{0,0}, {50,30}, {100,120}};
    clustergen(110, v, "clustergen_out.dat", "clustergen_report.dat", 1, 0);

}
```

Comment: Please note, this question can be depreciated in favor of [version 0.2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/172754/a-simple-cluster-generator-v0-2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Overview:

Instantiating a random engine is relatively expensive. Also creating one each loop does not increase your entropy (more likely decreases but I am not a mathamtician so don't homd me to that). **BUT** it is fine to create it once:

```
// Do this once at the beginning of the function
std::default_random_engine gen(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
```

#### Modern C++ techniques:

```
// C++ 03
for (std::vector<std::vector<double>>::iterator c_iter = c.begin(); c_iter != c.end(); ++c_iter)
```

In C++ 11 we can let the compiler determine the type:

```
// C++ 11
for (auto c_iter = c.begin(); c_iter != c.end(); ++c_iter)
```

In C++14 they introduced range based for()

```
// C++ 14
for (auto& cValue : c) //  Note:: cValue => *c_iter from the above examples.
```

Looking at the inner loop:

```
    std::vector<double>::iterator d_iter = (*c_iter).begin();
    while (d_iter != (*c_iter).end()) {
        // STUFF
        ++d_iter;
    }
```

We replace this `while` loop with a `for` loop.

```
   for (auto d_iter = (*c_iter).begin(); d_iter != (*c_iter).end(); ++d_iter)
```

Which of course we can then apply all the above transformations on and get the same result:

```
   for (auto dValue: *c_iter)
```

We should also note that `->` is short hand for `(*).`

```
   // eg:
   (*c_iter).begin()

   // written more succinctly as:
   c_iter->begin()
```

#### Over Complex

```
(k % c.size() == 0) ? (subsec = (k + ct) / c.size()) : (subsec = 1 + ((k + ct) / c.size()));
```

First of that is hard to read. Spread it out:

```
(k % c.size() == 0)
    ? (subsec = (k + ct) / c.size())
    : (subsec = 1 + ((k + ct) / c.size()));
```

Second this relies on sideeffects of the expression. This is usually not a good idea. Let expressions by simple (with no side affects). Use the result of the whole thing to do the assignment:

```
subsec = (k % c.size() == 0)
    ? ((k + ct) / c.size())
    : (1 + ((k + ct) / c.size()));


// Also this:
rout << (norm) ? "normally" : "uniformly";  // from your monstrocity.
```

I also think I see a common sub expression in there. Extract that and assign it to a meaningful variable name to help document your code:

```
auto someMeaningfulName = (k + ct) / c.size();
subsec = (k % c.size() == 0)
    ? someMeaningfulName
    : 1 + someMeaningfulName;
```

OK. Now I can make this even more readable:

```
auto someMeaningfulName = (k + ct) / c.size();
subsec = someMeaningfulName + ((k % c.size() == 0) ? 0 : 1);
```

#### One line per declaration

```
std::ofstream fout, rout;
fout.open(file_out);
rout.open(file_rpt);
```

Use one line to declare each variable (and put some more meaningful names on them). Also there is no reason to explicitly call the `open()` method as this is handeled by the constructor:

```
std::ofstream fout(file_out);
std::ofstream rout(file_rpt);
```

Comment: I think range based for is C++11, and it was not modified until C++17.

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you Loki. A note on your "Looking at the inner loop" section: the only reason this was a while() instead of a for() was because `d_iter` was using a peeking function - I think this was old code and will adjust accordingly.

Comment: Also `rout << (norm) ? "normally" : "uniformly";` appears to need parenthesis: `rout << ((norm) ? "normally" : "uniformly");` which is interesting - I always thought the ternary operator had the highest precedence?