# A Simple Cluster Generator v0.31

Tags: c++, beginner, c++11, random, clustering

[NOTE] This question can be depreciated in favor of [version 0.32](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/173609/a-simple-cluster-generator-v0-32).

This is a code revision of a [previous post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/173185/a-simple-cluster-generator-v0-3) and works well.

The purpose of this code is to produce a universe of points, randomly generated around predetermined centroids, provided from the user as either a vector of vectors or from a file. The final product is an output of sample points produced around the centroids, to be used for fake data analysis in another program. The objective here is brevity and speed. This most recent version is about 100 lines between the `.h` and `.cpp`.

## Changes in This Version:

- Reporting is completely gone. This returned the `.h` and `.cpp` back down to ~100 lines of code.
- I/O is now passed by `ostream` only (instead of `string`), allowing for console output and other uses.
- `cluster_set` has been simplified - members have been decreased significantly.
- `cluster_set` now maintains a function pointer toward a distribution which can be modified by the user
- Variables have been renamed for clarity.
- `const`s have been removed for the time being; ran into errors, particularly when `const`ing any of the parameters except `unsigned int`.
- Got rid of a default constructor to force-intake centroids on any construction; this makes object instancing more fluid (there is no reason to have a centroid-empty `cluster_set`).

My goal is two-fold: speed and conciseness. Speed takes precedence over conciseness, but thankfully they tend to go hand in hand.

## Future Implementations:

I am very happy with the state of this program so far (nearly every major issue has been addressed)...

- I've been successfully using a time-based randomized seed, however it's been suggested (a number of times) that I switch to `std::random_device{}()`. However, this seed is not producing random results - I get the same "random" set of points every time I run the program. Perhaps I'm implementing incorrectly?
- The way this is currently coded, the default distribution must exist outside of the `cluster_set` member functions. The `distribution` function pointer (a member of `cluster_set`) then points to this global function. I run into scoping issues with the function pointer if I try to include the default function as a member variable, and I feel this would bloat the code unnecessarily to try to force this to work. One thing I like about the current state is the "smallness" of the code. It just feels a little "dangling" to have a global function in a `.h`.
- The distribution currently works on a dimension-by-dimension basis: you pass in a dimension's value, you get back a random number near that value. In [v0.2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/172754/a-simple-cluster-generator-v0-2) it was observed that it may be valuable to code this in a point-by-point basis (you pass in an entire point, you get back an entire randomized dimensional set near that point). When I attempted this, it bloated the code - it is also something not needed for my purposes.
- Error handling.

## Notes:

- I understand `this->` is a matter of personal preference in most cases. The reason I'm partial to it is I often code when I'm tired and `this->` reminds me that I'm looking at a member variable, not at something else (like a function parameter).
- I am very happy with this update - shout out to [Justin](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/49895/justin) for your pivotal suggestions on [v0.2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/172754/a-simple-cluster-generator-v0-2) and [v0.3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/173185/a-simple-cluster-generator-v0-3). A thank you to the rest of the community as well!

## clustergen.h

```
#ifndef CLUSTERGEN_H
#define CLUSTERGEN_H

#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

double default_distribution(double &);        // The default distribution function (Normal)

class cluster_set {
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> centroids;   // Centroids around which to evenly generate all points
    double (*distribution)(double &);             // Changeable pointer to a distribution function

    void import_centroids(std::vector<std::vector<double>> &);   // Import centroids from vector

public:
    cluster_set(std::ifstream &, char);                // Import centroids from file with specified delimiter
    cluster_set(std::vector<std::vector<double>> &);   // Import centroids from vector on construction

    void clustergen(unsigned int, std::ostream &, char);
    void set_distribution(double (*new_distribution)(double &)) { this->distribution = new_distribution; }
};

#endif //CLUSTERGEN_H
```

## clustergen.cpp

```
#include "clustergen.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <sstream>

double default_distribution(double & dimension) {
    static std::default_random_engine gen(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());   // Random seed
    // static std::default_random_engine gen(std::random_device{}());   // Not randomizing??
    std::normal_distribution<double> distr(dimension, 1);
    return distr(gen);
}

// Import centroids from file with specified delimiter into a temporary vector - calls import_centroids()
cluster_set::cluster_set(std::ifstream & input_file, char delimiter) {
    this->distribution = default_distribution;
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> temp_centroid_vector;
    while (std::getline(input_file, line)) {
        while ((line.length() == 0) && !(input_file.eof())) {
            std::getline(input_file, line);   // Skips blank lines in file
        }
        std::string parameter;
        std::stringstream ss(line);
        std::vector<double> temp_point;
        if ((line.length() != 0)) {
            while (std::getline(ss, parameter, delimiter)) {
                temp_point.push_back(atof(parameter.c_str()));
            }
            temp_centroid_vector.push_back(temp_point);
        }
        this->import_centroids(temp_centroid_vector);
    }
}

// Import centroids from vector on construction
cluster_set::cluster_set(std::vector<std::vector<double>> & centroid_vector) {
    this->distribution = default_distribution;
    this->import_centroids(centroid_vector);
}

// Primary centroid import function
void cluster_set::import_centroids(std::vector<std::vector<double>> & centroid_vector) {
    for (auto centroid_vector_iter = centroid_vector.begin(); centroid_vector_iter != centroid_vector.end(); ++centroid_vector_iter) {
        if (this->centroids.empty()) {
            this->centroids.push_back(*centroid_vector_iter);
        } else if (centroid_vector_iter->size() == this->centroids.front().size()) {   // Assures dimensional integrity
            this->centroids.push_back(*centroid_vector_iter);
        }
    }
}

// Primary cluster generator - aborts if no centroids have been imported.
void cluster_set::clustergen(unsigned int k, std::ostream & output, char delimiter) {
    if (this->centroids.empty()) {
        output << "ERROR: No centroids have been imported. Aborting operation.";
        return;
    }
    if (k < this->centroids.size()) { k = this->centroids.size(); }
    const unsigned int n = k / this->centroids.size();   // Evenly distributes points across centroids
    unsigned rem = k % this->centroids.size();           // Evenly distributes points across centroids
    for (auto centroid_iter = this->centroids.begin(); centroid_iter != this->centroids.end(); ++centroid_iter) {
        unsigned int subset = n + (rem ? 1 : 0);         // Evenly distributes points across centroids
        while (subset) {
            std::vector<double> temp_point;
            for (auto dimension_iter = centroid_iter->begin(); dimension_iter != centroid_iter->end(); ++dimension_iter) {
                temp_point.push_back(distribution(*dimension_iter));
            }
            for (auto temp_point_iter = temp_point.begin(); temp_point_iter != temp_point.end(); ++temp_point_iter) {
                if (temp_point_iter != temp_point.begin()) { output << delimiter; }
                output << (*temp_point_iter);
            }
            if (subset - 1) { output << "\n"; };
            --subset;
            if (rem) { --rem; }   // Evenly distributes points across centroids
        }
        auto centroid_iter_peek = centroid_iter;
        ++centroid_iter_peek;
        if (centroid_iter_peek != centroids.end()) { output << "\n"; };
    }
}
```

## main.h

(Contains a few examples)

```
#include "clustergen.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

double new_distribution(double & dimension) {
    static std::default_random_engine gen(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());   // Random seed
    // static std::default_random_engine gen(std::random_device{}());   // Not randomizing??
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distr(-5, 5);
    return dimension + 10 * distr(gen);
}

int main() {

    std::vector<std::vector<double>> v = {{-100, -100},
                                          {100,  100},
                                          {1000, 1000}};
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> v2 = {{-100, -100},
                                           {1},
                                           {100,  100},
                                           {1,    2, 3},
                                           {1000, 1000}}; // Dimensional mismatch

    std::ostream &output_console = std::cout;
    std::ofstream output_file;

    cluster_set my_clusters(v);                        // Vector constructor
    my_clusters.clustergen(11, output_console, ',');   // Generate 10 random points to the console (',' delimited)

    std::ofstream out2;
    out2.open("clustergen_out_2.dat");
    cluster_set my_clusters2(v2);                       // Vector constructor with invalid dimensional points (omitted)
    my_clusters2.set_distribution(new_distribution);    // Setting a user-defined distribution
    my_clusters2.clustergen(11, out2, ',');             // Generate 11 random points to "clustergen_out_2.dat" (',' delimited)

    std::ifstream v3;
    v3.open("clustergen_in.dat");
    std::ofstream out3;
    out3.open("clustergen_out_3.dat");
    cluster_set my_clusters3(v3,'$');          // File const. with user-spec. delimiter - blank lines and invalid dimensions omitted
    my_clusters3.clustergen(13, out3, '@');    // Generate 13 random points to "clustergen_out_3.dat" (',' delimited)

}
```

## clustergen_in.dat

(Used in the `main.h` examples above)

```
210$220
230$240

250$260$270
280$290

200
```

Comment: Are you using .. what's it called .. MingW or Cygwin? I've heard that the implementation they use for `std::random_device` is completely not random

Comment: Ahh, I am using mingw - I'll take a look at the documentation.

Comment: So IIRC and mingw's implementation of `std::random_device` is completely not random (think it returns a single int), there isn't much you can do, sadly (using only standard C++). It's definitely a flaw in mingw's implementation, even though it is standard compliant. You may be able to use some sort of `boost::random_device`, though

Comment: I'm not going to be reviewing your code thoroughly yet, but at a glance, the design of your class is pretty good. Good job.

Comment: I feel that posting multiple versions of the code for the same thing, and twice within the same day, is excessive.

Comment: @einpoklum I disagree. Iterative reviews are welcomed on Code Review. While having two iterations posted this close together may be a bit abnormal, the changes are significant enough that it's okay. It's not a bad idea to wait a bit longer, though, so that you can get more suggestions before the next iteration

Comment: @Justin: Well, if other people don't mind I suppose I shouldn't either.

Comment: @einpoklum - I'm uncertain why v0.3 is showing as being posted today, as it was posted yesterday (there are several comments that were posted 22+ hours ago; an impossibility if I posted today). I've been attempting to rigorously follow the community guidelines [here](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c) and [here](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1065/how-to-post-a-follow-up-question?rq=1). I'm also making sure not to post more than once per day - would you recommend less?

Comment: @Justin indeed - that was my biggest reason for posting so close: the sheer magnitude of changes. I'll endeavor to slow it down a tad; I have a few other projects the pursue in the mean time.

Comment: @Miller: Yes, I would recommend less. I mean, if people are willing to oblige you, it's all fine between friends, but if you're not sure that is the case, I'd take the time to try out my own work based on people's suggestions, then come back for another round.

Comment: @einpoklum Thanks for the input; I've been receiving a huge amount of community input on v0.1 through v0.3 and implementing their suggested changes, making sure to notate these changes in each following version. I understand my turnaround has been very fast - I'll slow it down.

Comment: Please note, this question can be depreciated in favor of version [0.32](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/173609/a-simple-cluster-generator-v0-32).

Answer (score 2):

By community recommendation, I will wait 48 hours before posting a version update. Two significant errors have been discovered and will be corrected in the next version:

## Erratic Point Generation

The call to `this->import_centroids()` in `cluster_set::cluster_set(std::ifstream & input_file, char delimiter)` needs to be one level up, outside of the while loop. This was resulting in strange behavior, ultimately not generating the correct amount of points in the output file. The correct code is:

```
cluster_set::cluster_set(std::ifstream & input_file, char delimiter) {
    this->distribution = default_distribution;
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> temp_centroid_vector;
    while (std::getline(input_file, line)) {
        while ((line.length() == 0) && !(input_file.eof())) {
            std::getline(input_file, line);   // Skips blank lines in file
        }
        std::string parameter;
        std::stringstream ss(line);
        std::vector<double> temp_point;
        if ((line.length() != 0)) {
            while (std::getline(ss, parameter, delimiter)) {
                temp_point.push_back(atof(parameter.c_str()));
            }
            temp_centroid_vector.push_back(temp_point);
        }
    }
    this->import_centroids(temp_centroid_vector);  // THIS HAS BEEN CORRECTED
}
```

## Incorrect Remainder Computation

`rem` was being decremented within the `while(subset)` loop, resulting in an erratically persistent remainder. Moving one level up, outside the loop, corrected this:

```
void cluster_set::clustergen(unsigned int k, std::ostream & output, char delimiter) {
    if (this->centroids.empty()) {
        output << "ERROR: No centroids have been imported. Aborting operation.";
        return;
    }
    if (k < this->centroids.size()) { k = this->centroids.size(); }
    unsigned int ct = 0;
    const unsigned int n = k / this->centroids.size();   // Evenly distributes points across centroids
    unsigned int rem = k % this->centroids.size();       // Evenly distributes points across centroids
    for (auto centroid_iter = this->centroids.begin(); centroid_iter != this->centroids.end(); ++centroid_iter) {
        unsigned int subset = n + (rem ? 1 : 0);         // Evenly distributes points across centroids
        while (subset) {
            std::vector<double> temp_point;
            for (auto dimension_iter = centroid_iter->begin(); dimension_iter != centroid_iter->end(); ++dimension_iter) {
                temp_point.push_back(distribution(*dimension_iter));
            }
            for (auto temp_point_iter = temp_point.begin(); temp_point_iter != temp_point.end(); ++temp_point_iter) {
                if (temp_point_iter != temp_point.begin()) { output << delimiter; }
                output << (*temp_point_iter);
            }
            if (subset - 1) { output << "\n"; };
            --subset;
        }
        if (rem) { --rem; }   // THIS HAS BEEN CORRECTED
        auto centroid_iter_peek = centroid_iter;
        ++centroid_iter_peek;
        if (centroid_iter_peek != centroids.end()) { output << "\n"; };
    }
}
```